# Proguard-rules.pro not helping while compilation

Tags: android-proguard

I set  **minifyEnabled** value to **true** and got a lot of errors while compiling my project. Like this one:

```
Warning:ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.overlay.location.MyLocationOverlay: can't find referenced class cb
```

I tried to add some lines like

```
-keep class ru.yandex.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.yandex.**
```

to my proguard-rules.pro file for the libraries that cause these warnings.

In build.gradle file I have

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

although getDefaultProguardFile is underlined and shows a warning "cannot resolve symbol 'getDefaultProguardFile' ". But they say that it doesn't affect any functionality, so I assume that my proguard-file is used.
But it doesn't help, I still get warnings on the libraries I already set to "keep" and "dontwarn".

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I found my mistake.

You also need to add "keep interface <...>"
And I made a mistake in package prefix of "yandex" library.